# Zabbix frontend dashboard not working after system reboot

Tags: zabbix, ubuntu-server

We are running zabbix on ubuntu server, and recently we rebooted the machine, after reboot Zabbix dashboard is not showing up. Although, we are still receiving the alert messages.

Ubuntu version 18.04.3 LTS;
Zabbix Version 4.4.4

error:
This site cant' be reached
ipaddress took too long to respond

ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

I tried sudo systemctl status apache2

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Okp9.png)

Comment: please add more details, eventual error messages. Check that Zabbix-web is running, the status of database..

Comment: Thanks for your reply, there are no error messages, I just cannot access the Gui interface of Zabbix ie, http://serverip/zabbix, its running on the backend and I can still receive all the alert messages, but I cannot open the gui interface . I dont know how I can check the status of database and Zabbix-web

Comment: Result of `systemctl status httpd` command? Or `ps -ef | grep http`?

Comment: Hi Iron, I am getting this error could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue using these commands:

systemctl start firewalld

sudo ufw allow 10050/tcp

systemctl stop firewalld

sudo systemctl restart zabbix-server